# What parameters for setvbuf perform the same action as setbuf(stdin, NULL) did?

Tags: c, stdin, deprecated

I have the question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549/how-to-properly-flush-stdin-in-fgets-loop).

The top answer had two recommendations, and one of them (which was presented as slightly more reliable) was to use `setbuf(stdin, NULL);`. However, the `setbuf()` function [is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setbuf?view=vs-2019), and the [replacement function is `setvbuf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?view=vs-2019). I am unsure how to use the parameters for this new function in a way that replicates the old function; how do I do this?

Background: when I use `getchar()` in a loop, the second iteration of the loop always reads the '\n' character next, and I want to get rid of that.

Comment: Can you be more clear on why you want to disable buffering?  If it's to avoid problems with newline interlacing between `scanf` and `fgets`, as alluded to in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549/how-to-properly-flush-stdin-in-fgets-loop), that's a horrible way to "solve" that problem, and I'm not at all sure it'd even work.

Comment: At least 99% of the time, if you're trying to "flush the input buffer", it's because of recurring problems with `scanf` that are best solved some other way.  Please don't try to flush input (much less disable input buffering for this reason).  Please either learn how to use `scanf` correctly, or (since using it correctly is all but impossible), learn about alternatives to `scanf`.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Comment: @SteveSummit I'll edit this into the question in a moment, but I'm attempting to use `getchar()` in a loop.

Comment: *when I use getchar() in a loop, the second iteration of the loop always reads the '\n' character next* It sounds like you're asking the user to type a character, and the user is typing a character and hitting the Enter key, so you're getting two characters.  That's correct and expected behavior, and "flushing" won't help.

Comment: If you're expecting a 1-character response from the user, and depending on what kind of program you're writing, I recommend either (1) investigating how to [read input immediately without waiting for the Return key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152381) or (2) reading a *line* of input using `fgets` and then (after stripping the newline from the buffer) complaining if it's not a line of length 1.

Comment: You are on a wrong road, by a hundred miles.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your stated question, the best `setvbuf` equivalent of

```
setbuf(stdin, NULL);
```

should be

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Contrary to the note in the documentation you linked, however, I'm not aware of `setbuf` being deprecated, however, and I'm not aware of any disincentives to using it.

And, as I mentioned in the comments, if the reason you want to disable buffering is as a workaround for the problem that `scanf` tends to leave newlines "in the buffer" thus causing problems later, I would say that disabling buffering entirely is a particularly poor way of addressing that problem.

Comment: Would you disagree with the answer to the linked question? If setvbuf is a poor solution to my problem, I'm not sure how to find the correct solution without asking a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Brandon_J I disagree strongly with the parts of that answer recommending `fflush(stdin)` and `setbuf(stdin, NULL)`, yes.

Comment: heh, that's pretty much the entire answer. Would it be out of line for me to ask what your answer to that question would be?

Comment: Also, VS 2019 doesn't allow setbuf (says it's deprecated).

Comment: @Brandon_J This comment box is way too small for a full answer to that question.  If you use poor input techniques in C, newline management can be a huge problem.  But if you use good techniques (like, use `fgets` for everything), it's generally not a problem at all.  If you *are* having newline problems, my suggestions would be (1) don't use `scanf`, (2) if you must use `scanf`, don't mix it with other input methods like `getchar` and `fgets`, and (3) if you must mix, meaning that you do need to flush newlines, do so using `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)`.

Comment: @Brandon_J There's a big difference between "Microsoft says X is deprecated" and "X is disallowed".  I don't believe `setbuf` is disallowed anywhere, and I don't believe it's deprecated by anyone other than Microsoft, either.

Comment: @Brandon_J When Microsoft says something is deprecated, it's bullsh*t. When ISO says something is deprecated, it's true.

Comment: @Brandon_J *what would your answer to that question be?* I've now [written it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549/how-to-properly-flush-stdin-in-fgets-loop/59119187#59119187).

Comment: @Brandon_J The linked question fully deserves to be closed, and the accepted answer has no useful content. Ask a question that shows your program, its input verbatim, its desired behaviour, and its actual behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage states this (added parameters to `setbuf` for ease of understanding):

> The other three calls are, in effect, simply aliases for calls to `setvbuf()`.  The `setbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf)` function is exactly equivalent to the call
>
> ```
> setvbuf(stream, buf, buf ? _IOFBF : _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
> ```

Therefore, your call would be equivalent to:

```
setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
```

because [`NULL` is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459743/is-null-always-false).

However, a much easier way to avoid the `\n` in a loop with `getchar` is to simply do this:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if(c == '\n')
        continue;
    /* use c as a character */
}
```

I'd also like to note that `setbuf` isn't deprecated. As a general rule, all of the functions not beginning with an underscore in Windows that are present in POSIX and not in the ANSI C standard are "deprecated" in Microsoft's eyes. If you use the underscore-prefixed versions, though, your code won't be portable. What a rabbit hole.